# I get a NON Error when I get the date from hidden input but when I input the date manually I get the time working, what could be the problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a NON Error when I get the date from hidden input but when I input the date manually I get the time working, what could be the problem:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="counter_value" id="counter_value" value="2019/9/10">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
      var counter_value = $("#counter_value").val();
      alert(counter_value);
      // counter_value = counter_value.replace("-", "/");
      $('#legacy-clock').countdown(counter_value, function(event) {
        var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime('' +
          '<span>%D</span> Days | ' +
          '<span>%H</span> Hours | ' +
          '<span>%M</span> Minutes | ' +
          '<span>%S</span> Seceonds '));
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: please post whole html, what is "legecy-clock"?

Comment: Please add additional content to your example. If you have anything loading async, then you might have more luck with `$(Window).on('load',...`.